# How to make Google Map dimension dynamic in a web page and replace existing direction

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="smallPadBottom floatLeft widthFromToDir">
    <span>From:</span>
    <br />
    <span class="percPadLeft"></span><input type="text" id="fromAdd" class="styledTB searchB" />
</div>
<div class="smallPadBottom floatLeft widthFromToDir">
    <span>To:</span>
    <br />
    <span class="percPadLeft"></span><input type="text" id="toAdd" class="styledTB searchB" />
</div>
<div class="smallPadBottom floatLeft widthDirBtn">
    <span></span>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="dirBtn" class="styledBtn styleDirection lightLinks" value="Get Direction" />
</div>
<div class="serviceHolder hidOverflow">
    <div id="mapHolder" class="mapHolder percPadRight floatLeft">
        <div id="mapPanel" style="width: 250px; height: 350px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="dirPanel" class="dirPanel smallPercPadLeft floatLeft"></div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {

    $("#dirBtn").on("click", function () {
        $("#dirPanel").text("");
        displayMap();
        alert("test");
    });
});

function displayMap() {
    alert("inside function");
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapPanel'), {
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dirPanel'));

    var request = {
        origin: $("#fromAdd").val(),
        destination: $("#toAdd").val(),
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2kbaqhyr/

How do I make the map DIV (`mapPanel`) the same width (23%) as the parent DIV (`mapHolder`). I want to make it responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS. Set `position: relative;` on `.mapHolder`, and `width: 100%;` on `#mapPanel` (inline, or it will be overriden). Or you can use `!important` to override the inline style.

Comment: Don't I have to set a pixel dimension for inline?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that, but I did answer your question and it works for me. If you have any other questions, please amend.

Comment: Can you modify the JSFiddle for me? Because I changed to this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls0Lgg7d/ and no map is showing up for me :/

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/2kbaqhyr/2/ . Your width of 250px was set inline in the html, and I believe you had an error in your CSS selectors: (`.mapHolder.mapPanel` should be `.mapHolder .mapPanel`)

Comment: I just realized it cannot be `.mapPanel` as it is an ID but it is working regardless... Odd!

Comment: Oh, right. It's working because I changed the width inline in your HTML as well. The parent div has a class so that CSS rule is being picked up. The child doesn't, but that's being done inline anyway.